# How do I highlight particular numbered-valued cells based on text from another row?

Tags: excel

I want to make it easier for my co-worker to 'highlight' certain numbered valued 'amounts', to separate what the cell value(s) references to (one of the text values would be an '**Invoice**' while the other would be '**Payment**').

In my/his case, you would have the 'Amount' row (starting from **H6** to **H13**), contain particular cells that are highlighted/filled with Red. All based if and only, on the 'Transaction Type' row (that begins from **C6** to **C13**), where the **text** must be 'Payment'.

Here's an imagine example of what I want to try to get (arrows references to particular text value where the highlight would occur across that cell/row):

https://scontent-a-mia.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/1546414_583304388416036_1014225178_n.jpg

I can imagine that this would be very complex, but if anyone has an idea on how to make this possible, please let me know. If this isn't possible, thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, then what you need is [Conditional Formatting](http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html).